# Why do ruby split statements with space separators return different values?

Tags: arrays, ruby-2.0

For example these two lines which are identical other than separator return different arrays.

```
"1,2,,3,4,,".split(',')
=> ["1", "2", "", "3", "4"] 
"1 2  3 4  ".split(' ')
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Comment: More specifically how can I split on whitespace and get the first array returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking for, you can either pass in an empty string:

```
 '1 2  3 4  '.split( '' )
 # => ["1", " ", "2", " ", " ", "3", " ", "4", " ", " "]
```

Or use regex:

```
 '1 2  3 4  '.split( /\s/ )
 # => ["1", "2", "", "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a single whitespace passed to the method `String#split` has special meaning.

From [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-split):

> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace characters ignored.

Comment: How can I make contiguous whitespace not ignored?

Comment: Getting the trailing whitespace is tricky. See if a regex `/\s/` or an empty string `""` give you what you want.